# excel vba doesnt follow save path and saves in my documents

Tags: vba, excel, path, save

I am quite new to vba. I wrote a piece of code to save an excel workbook. the original save path works and the file gets saved there, but when i try to change it (to a shared directory) it doesn't listen.Instead, it just saves in My Documents. Below is the code that works.

Any help would be appreciated

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
ChDir "C:\Users\SI\Desktop\Generator"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    Range("B4").Value & " TRS - " & Range("E6").Value & " vs " _
    & Range("E7").Value & " - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"), FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
Sheets("ST").Select
```

Comment: Do you want to save a specific sheet or the workbook to a directory?

Comment: I extracted a sheet from the workbook and created a new workbook, so i guess i want to save the new workbook

Comment: You cannot use `ChDir` with UNC (network) paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the full path in the Filename argument for the SaveAs

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\SI\Desktop\Generator\" & Range("B4").Value & " TRS - " & Range("E6").Value & " vs " _
    & Range("E7").Value & " - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy"), FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
Sheets("ST").Select
```